# JMS durable subscriber in a cluster with multiple instances

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, message-driven-bean, jms-topic

I am going to be using Payara BTW....

Suppose I have:

1. A JMS Topic
2. An MDB configured as a **durable** topic subscriber
3. Multiple instances of the MDB are deployed across the cluster and they are all using the same client ID value to make the **durable** subscription.

If this is the scenario, and given the way client ID values and **durable** subscriptions work, is it correct to say that only 1 of the MDB instances across the cluster will succeed in connecting and the others will fail?

Thanks!

Suppose you have a MDB deployed to a cluster, so there are multiple MDB instances across the cluster attempting to listen.

Answer (score 0):

As of the JMS 2.0 API [1], you can share the same durable subscription across nodes in an application cluster.

> The following change has been made to aid scalability:
>
> Applications are now permitted to create multiple consumers on the same durable or non-durable topic subscription. In previous versions of JMS only a single consumer was permitted.

You can use the JMS 2.0+ API to create a shared durable consumer using the JMSContext.createSharedDurableConsumer() methods [2]

[1] https://java.net/projects/jms-spec/pages/JMS20FinalRelease#What_s_new_in_JMS_2.0? (the ? is part of the link - go figure)

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/JMSContext.html#createSharedDurableConsumer-javax.jms.Topic-java.lang.String-

Comment: I'm actually trying to ensure only 1 will handle the message

Comment: In your scenario, it appears that you want your topic to act as a queue. The semantics for topics are such that all configured clients can subscribe and receive messages. In a queue, however, only one  consumer will. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e24429/appx_topic_or_queue.htm#EOITW196  Is there any way you can set up a queue rather than a JMS topic?

Comment: A queue wouldn't work.  I need multiple clients (A,B,C) to be able to consume the same message, but if there are multiple instances of a client (A1,A2,..,N) the messages should be consumed by only one of the instances.  Queues I don't think would get me there.

Comment: @MichaelRemijan : I am into the similar situation now. How did you resolve your issue?

I am running my subscriber in a clustered environment (A1, A2, A3) so all these subscriber instances start picking and processing the same TOPIC.
How can i restrict it in a way if A1 picks some TOPIC then other twos (A2 and A3) shouldn't pick that one.

Comment: I never did implement a working solution for this.  After much research, the solution is to configure your broker to forward messages onto other queues.  So it would work kind of like this.  Custer instances A1, A2, A3, are configured to listen to queue A.  Custer instances B1, B2, B3, are configured to listen to Queue B.  The message producer publishes a message onto Queue X.  The broker is then configured to automatically forward messages from Queue X onto both Queue A and Queue B.  This achieves the goal of the producer knowing about only one queue but multiple clusters get the message

Comment: If you pursue this and get a working example please let me know.  I'd like to collaborate on a blog article.

Comment: MichaelRemijan, did you try the solution given by @MichaelPeacock to configure “shared durable consumer”? I am in same situation and old like to know if you had any challenges with that.