# JMS1.x subscribers/clients in a Websphere clustered environment picking the same TOPIC

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms, camel-jms

Multiple instances of my subscriber/client application are running in a clustered environment and all of them start picking up the same TOPIC.

Is there a way to restrict the subscribers to stop picking the TOPIC which has already been picked by some different subscriber/client.

Please note that i must use the TOPICs and i can't change it to use Messages due to some business requirements. (similar to this [JMS durable subscriber in a cluster with multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38151575/jms-durable-subscriber-in-a-cluster-with-multiple-instances))

Comment: First my comment is assuming you are using IBM MQ. Is the problem that when all nodes subscribe to the TOPIC they all receive each message that is published?  If so would it work if each message that is published was delivered only to one of the subscribers connected not all of them? If this sounds like a solution, then at JMS1.x (MQ v7.5 and earlier - these are all currently out of support) you can use a feature called "Cloned subscriptions", with JMS2.0 (MQ v8.0 and later) you can use a feature called "Shared subscriptions".

Comment: @JoshMc : Yes we are using IBM-MQ and thats exactly what we want to achieve, to deliver each TOPIC only to one subscriber.

Comment: and we want to achieve it with JMS 1.x because thats the version our client is using and they are not willing to upgrade.

Comment: What I proposed is not to deliver each "TOPIC" to only one subscriber but to deliver each message published to a "TOPIC" to only one subscriber.  If this is what you want them look at [Properties of WebSphere MQ classes for JMS objects > CLONESUPP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q112010_.htm).

Comment: @JoshMc: Okay got it. I am using javax.jms apis and getting the connectionFactory from webSphere via JNDI. I am unable to find any CLONESUPP property with that connectionFactory. Where can i set that property if its not available programatically with JMS1.O lib? Please note that my WebSphere version is 8.5.5 and WEBSPHERE MQ version is 8.0.x

Comment: It is a IBM JMS1.0 extension.  I did provide a link to the docs.